# Using c# GetFiles Length but only count the files with certain amount of chars in filename

Tags: c#, linq, getfiles

So i'm using the simple

```
ImgFilesCount = ImgDirInfo.GetFiles("*.jpg").Length;
```

to figure out how many files are in a dir.  But I need it to only count files that have exactly 26 characters in the file name.  I tried

```
ImgFilesCount = ImgDirInfo.GetFiles("?????????????????????????.jpg").Length;
```

But it didn't work.  Is the only option to do a foreach loop and check each filename and increment the counter?  I have a feeling linq can probably do this with a .Where statement but I don't know any Linq.

Comment: .Where(fname => condition(fname.Length))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe

```
int count = ImgDirInfo.EnumerateFiles("*.jpg").Count(f => f.Name.Length == 26);
```

[`EnumerateFiles`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383574.aspx) is more efficient since it doesn't need to load all files into memory before it starts processing.

- When you use EnumerateFiles, you can start enumerating the collection of FileInfo objects before the whole collection is returned.
- When you use GetFiles, you must wait for the whole array of FileInfo objects to be returned before you can access the array.

Comment: Good point about `EnumerateFiles`. Just tiny note: isn't `Count` will load all files making streaming nature of `EnumerateFiles` irrelevant?

Comment: @IlyaIvanov Well, no. That's the whole beauty of iterators. The `Count` extension method consumes the query during the counting process.

Comment: @YoryeNathan as result making more calls to hard disk?

Comment: @YoryeNathan: In this case Ilya is right since `Count` needs to enumerate all files with the given search pattern. So in general it's better to use `Directory.EnumerateFiles` instead if you only need the filename.

Comment: @IlyaIvanov It's Performance vs Memory. I usually go for performance, but it depends on the situation. This is only to point out that in some cases the `EnumerateFiles` method is more appropriate *even though* it does consume the query in the end.

Comment: @YoryeNathan agree, but it's hard to say where performance is better without empirical evidence. Anyway, I should definitely need to remember `EnumerateFiles`. I've knew about `ReadLines` vs `ReadAllLines`, now Tim brought another streaming vs non-streaming files reading,

Answer (score 3):

```
ImgFilesCount = ImgDirInfo.GetFiles("*.jpg")
                          .Where(file => file.Name.Length == 26)
                          .Count();
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
        string[] files = Directory
                         .EnumerateFiles(@"c:\Users\x074\Downloads" , "*.jpg" , SearchOption.AllDirectories )
                         .Where( path => Path.GetFileName(path).Length > 20 )
                         .ToArray()
                         ;
```

Comment: _"exactly 26 characters"_ is somewhat different to `Length > 20`.